# Undefined Index Error - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am setting up a link that allows a user to add recipe data to the original page. The data will go through to the mysql table and be displayed on the page with the other recipes. Originally what was working was the INSERT INTO recipes (recipe_name) by itself but I needed to enter all the columns you see below and they were not displaying.  When I added the other columns I got the undefined index error. I also tried using a if isset command but that did nothing. I have spent almost an hour looking around SO for an answer to Undefined Index Error and have not found anything related to adding multiple columned info to the database through the website.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
        try
        {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO recipes 
                        (recipe_name, recipe_ingred, recipe_direct, 
                         author_name, author_email) 
                     VALUES ("' . $_POST['recipe_name, 
                                          recipe_ingred, 
                                          recipe_direct, 
                                          author_name, 
                                          author_email']
                                .'")';
            $result = $pdo->exec($sql);
            header('Location: recipes.php');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error performing insert: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="recipe_name">Recipe name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="recipe_name" name="recipe_name"><br>
            <label for="recipe_ingred">Recipe ingredients:</label>
            <textarea id="recipe_ingred" name="recipe_ingred" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><br>
            <label for="recipe_direct">Recipe directions:</label>
            <textarea id="recipe_direct" name="recipe_direct" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><br>
            <label for="recipe_name">Your name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="author_name" name="author_name"><br>
            <label for="recipe_name">Your email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="author_email" name="author_email"><br>
        </div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Submit recipe"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You cannot combine indexes like this: `$_POST['recipe_name, recipe_ingred, recipe_direct, author_name, author_email']`. Use the individual values: `"'".$_POST['recipe_name']."'","'".$_POST['recipe_ingred']."'",...`.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. Will remember that for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid syntax, and exposed to sql injection, You need to prepare the query:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO recipes 
            (recipe_name, recipe_ingred, recipe_direct, author_name, author_email)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['recipe_name'], 
                     $_POST['recipe_ingred'], 
                     $_POST['recipe_direct'], 
                     $_POST['author_name'], 
                     $_POST['author_email']));
```